# How can I match a pricenumber anywhere in a line of text with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the numbers, after the currency sign, in these four lines with the same regex:

1. Something $**95**+$**5** something
2. Something $**94.50**+$**5.50** something
3. Something €**94,50**+€**5,50** something
4. Something £**94.50**+£**5.50** something

My old regex only works on numbers with decimals:

```
(?<=[$€£])[0-9]+[.,][0-9]+
```

My new regex matches whole numbers but once it encounters the optional decimals it won't include them (like so: $**94**.50+$**5**.50):

```
(?<=[$€£])[0-9]+?[.,]?[0-9]+
```

How do I make it so that they are optional when not present but need to be included when they are present?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern `(?<=[$€£])[0-9]+[.,][0-9]+` the dot or the comma are not optional and the following digits are also not optional.

You could use an optional group using `?` and add both the dot or comma with the digits: `(?:[.,][0-9]+)?`

```
(?<=[$€£])[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ci8Mou/1)

Or match the currency sign and use a capturing group instead for the numbers:

```
[$€£]([0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ci8Mou/2)

Comment: works like a charm! will accept answer in 10min when SO allows me ;-)